# How to allow project creation in all groups by default in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

We have set up Gitlab internally on our company Intranet but we do not have a need for permissions inside Gitlab. We trust each other and instead want to make things as simple as possible.
So therefor we want *every logged in user to be able to create Projects in every Group*. I.E. we want groups to be open and default setting for new users to be developers in every group (even those created in the future).

Is that possible and if so, how do I (as an admin) accomplish that?

Or can I do a workaround somehow to accomplish our need to just use groups as "folders" for repos?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this by default without editing the code itself. You can. Even with the suggested answer below, only members of the group would be able to create new projects

Comment: you can create public groups...since OP has mentioned its a local server and users trust each other, there should be no problem with public groups.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public group in gitlab UI and under `{YOUR_GROUP_NAME} > General settings`, check the section `Permissions, LFS, 2FA`. Scroll down to `Allowed to create projects` section, and change the setting to `Developers + Maintainers`. Then, under the right pane section `members`, Add your users and give all of your users `Developer` or `Maintainer` access level. Now they should be able to create projects under that group name. They also can create new groups and create projects within their own groups, too.

Comment: This would work (thats our current solution). But it is unsustainable since there are over 20 users, and since it is LDAP more users can show up (newly employed). It relies on constant supervision to keep it updated.
Also, someone else may create a group and may very well forget to do this step.

Comment: Then I think your main problem is not technical, its organizational. There is a reason for keeping the roles separate and giving certain responsibilities and permissions. It's not because people don't trust each other, it is to make the work in order, avoid rework and avoid confusion. Especially in something as cryptic as code.
I highly recommend that you devise a plan for your code (or documents, whatever that is you are storing in gitlab) and a structure for your team. Going on like this will end you up with problems that not only stackoverflow, but no other technical forum can help.